# Why does std::map emplace need a copy constructor on gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The following code compiles well on Visual Studio's Visual C++ 19.0 compiler, but gcc 5.4.0 complains about the copy constructor being private.

```
#include <map>

class CMyClass
{
public:
  CMyClass(int) {};
private:
  CMyClass(const CMyClass&); // I want to avoid copy construction
};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, CMyClass> mymap;
  mymap.emplace(0, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
‘CMyClass::CMyClass(const CMyClass&)’ is private
```

Isn't avoiding copies exactly what `emplace` is for? Am I missing something?

Comment: so it needs a copy constructor but will not use it?

Comment: Looks like a bug in gcc 5.4. The same code [compiles with gcc 6](https://godbolt.org/g/KbvNSq).

Comment: @Bert sorry, my mistake. copy constructor is required in some cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid in C++11 as published.

The C++11 standard depicts two `pair` constructors with two parameters:

```
pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);
template<class U, class V> pair(U&& x, V&& y);
```

If the first gets chosen, you are doomed for obvious reasons.

The second overload does not participate in overload resolution if, as relevant here, "`V` is not implicitly convertible to `second_type`". Here, `V` is `int`, `second_type` is `CMyClass`. Is `int` implicitly convertible to `CMyClass`? No, because the declaration `CMyClass x = some_int;` is not well-formed, as in C++11 that declaration notionally constructs a `CMyClass` temporary from `some_int` and then moves it into x, but `CMyClass` cannot be moved.

The extra overloads GCC added - as is allowed - have similar constraints.

---

C++17 substantially revamped the constraints on `pair`'s constructors, which has the side effect of allowing your code to work. Implementers treated this as a retroactive defect fix, which is why GCC 6 accepts your code.

Comment: Ok, but how can you do this? Is there a way to emplace a non-copy constructable object in an std::map (GCC <6) ?

Answer (score 2):

GCC 5.4.0 is only checking if the types are convertible when enabling the overload in question:

```
  // DR 811.
  template<class _U1, class = typename
       enable_if<is_convertible<_U1, _T1>::value>::type>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
: first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
```

Whereas more recent versions of GCC checks if it is move constructible:

```
288       template<typename _U1, typename
289            enable_if<_PCCP::template
290                _MoveCopyPair<true, _U1, _T2>(),
291                          bool>::type=true>
292        constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
293        : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
```

In particular `_PCCP` is an alias for `_PCC<true, _T1, _T2>`. `_PCC` is a traits class that contains this function:

```
138       template <bool __implicit, typename _U1, typename _U2>
139       static constexpr bool _MoveCopyPair()
140       {
141     using __do_converts = __and_<is_convertible<_U1&&, _T1>,
142                   is_convertible<const _U2&, _T2>>;
143     using __converts = typename conditional<__implicit,
144                        __do_converts,
145                        __not_<__do_converts>>::type;
146     return __and_<is_constructible<_T1, _U1&&>,
147               is_constructible<_T2, const _U2&&>,
148               __converts
149               >::value;
150       }
```

Comment: That is the wrong overload of `pair` to use here; the correct overload should take `_U2` deduced type that implicitly converts to `_T2`, not a `T2` to copy-from.  This overload should be eliminated from consideration.  The existence of invalid ctors doesn't prove that there isn't a valid ctor, nor that this invalid ctor should be considered and generate hard errors.

Comment: @Yakk Note that `is_convertible<int, CMyClass>` is false before C++17 because of private copy and no move; that overload is disabled until the conditionally-explicit constructors adjusted the SFINAE constraints.

Comment: @Yakk No, it's not. Not without "guaranteed elision".

Comment: @T.C. Oh, I was thinking `CMyClass test() { return {int(7)}; }`, my bad